# Setting specific variables based on what value is set in cypress environment variables

Tags: angularjs, cypress

I have a custom command called Cypress.Commands.add("createCustomer")

I have a environment variable that specifies in which country this customer will be created.
but the problem is that within the createCustomer function, i would like to set other values based on what country the customer is actually being created. for specific countries there are diffrent currencies, so instead of having to change all the other env.variables i would like them to check like a do-while function.

```
if(Cypress.env('tenant')) = company_denmark{
Cypress.env('invoiceCurrency') = 'danish-crown',
Cypress.env('billcycle') = 'danish-billcycle-1'
})
```

Should i place this within the 'createCustomer' function, or can i place this IF-statement in cypress.env?

This is the create customer function;

```
Cypress.Commands.add("createCustomer", (sendEmail, billingIdName, invoiceCurrency) => {

/*
if(Cypress.env('tenant') = 'company_denmark', {
    Cypress.env('invoiceCurrency') = 'danish-crown',
    Cypress.env('billcycle') = 'danish-billcycle-1'
    })
*/

const todaysDate = Cypress.moment().format('DD MMM, YYYY')

cy.contains('Customers', {timeout: 15000}).click().then(($div) => {
    if($div.hasClass('is-expanded')) {
        $div.click().first()
    }
})

cy.contains('Create Customer', {timeout: 15000}).click()
    
cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
if($body.find('div[r6-popover="r6-create-customer-popover"]').length > 0)   {
    cy.get('[r6-permission-context="RETAIL"] > a').click({ force: true })
    }
})
cy.wait(1500)

cy.get('.r6loader', {timeout: 30000}).should('not.be.visible')

//skip to Customer Details
cy.r6WizardNext()

// fill in data
cy.get('#business-type').select('Individual')
cy.get('#industry-type').select('Professional Services')
cy.get('#trading-name').type('Testbolaget Cypress ' + todaysDate)
cy.get('#business-number').type('SE999999999901')

cy.get('select[name=customer-title]').select('Mr')
cy.get('input[name=contact-lastName]').type('Gunnar')
cy.get('input[name=contact-firstName]').type('Svensson')
cy.get('input[name=contact-middleName]').type('testarn')

cy.get('input[name=streetName]').type('Testgatan 21')
cy.get('input[name=postCode]').type('123 11')
cy.get('input[name=suburb]').type('Staden')
cy.get('select[name=country]').select('Sweden')

cy.get('select[name=preferred-contact-method]').select('Email')
cy.get('input[name=phoneNumberDayTime]').type('0822334455')
cy.get('input[name=phoneMobile]').type('467223344')
cy.get('input[name=email]').type('test@mail.com')

cy.get('input[name=telia-Id]').type('123456')
cy.get('select[name=company_code] > option')
  .eq(1)
  .then(option =>       cy.get('select[name=company_code]').select(option.val()))

cy.get('select[name=profit-Center-Telia] > option')
  .eq(1)
  .then(option => cy.get('select[name=profit-Center-Telia]').select(option.val()))

  cy.r6WizardNext()


if(invoiceCurrency) {
    cy.get('#invoiceCurrency').select(invoiceCurrency)
} else {
    cy.get('select[name=invoiceCurrency] > option')
      .eq(1)
      .then(option =>       cy.get('select[name=invoiceCurrency]').select(option.val()))
}


 cy.get('select[name=billCycleKey] > option')
  .eq(1)
  .then(option =>           cy.get('select[name=billCycleKey]').select(option.val()))


cy.get('input[name=email-to]').type('test@mail.com')
cy.get('select[name=email-type]').select('Telia Email Type')

cy.r6WizardNext()



cy.get('h4.modal-title:contains("Send summary email")', { timeout:       30000 })
if(sendEmail) {
    cy.fillAndSendSummaryEmail()
} else {
    cy.get('div.r6modal-buttons > button:contains("Cancel")').click()
}  


if(billingIdName) {
    cy.get('#r6-customerheader-accountnumber-label').then(($div) => {
        cy.wrap($div.text().trim()).as(billingIdName)
    })
} else {
    cy.get('#r6-customerheader-accountnumber-label').then(($div) => {
        cy.wrap($div.text().trim()).as('billingAccountId')
    })
}
})
```

Comment: Can you please post the code for your custom command createCustomer as well?

Comment: I'm not sure why these need to be environment variables. Cant you just pass the country to the command then work out the currency within the command?

Comment: from the command line i set the environment, we have 4 environments and 4 countries. And to try to make this custom command versatile, to work within these 16 diffrent possible combinations i want it to check what country it is currently in.

Comment: I'm still not sure why you are trying to set them as env variables within the command. Set the country via and env variable when you start Cypress and then use that within the command to set the currency as a normal JS variable.

Comment: @SimonD, the invoice currency do not need to be env variables, I just thought that would be the easiest. but how do i check within the cy.createCustomer() what tenant is set and then use that to set the correct 'invoiceCurrency' ?
This is what i came up with, but it does not like the code;

 if(Cypress.env('tenant') = 'NORWAY', {

  invoiceCurrency = 'Norweigan Krone'
  })
 if(Cypress.env('tenant') = 'DENMARK', {

  invoiceCurrency = 'Danish Krone'
  })
 if(Cypress.env('tenant') = 'FINLAND', {

  invoiceCurrency = 'Euro'
  })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is necessary to set the invoice currency and bill cycle as environment variables. At the beginning of your command you can just make the values local constants:

```
const tenant = Cypress.env('tenant');
const invoiceCurrency = getTenantCurrency(tenant);
const billcycle = getTenantBillcycle(tenant);
```

This code will run synchronously and the respective values will be available throughout the rest of the command code. `getTenantCurrency()` and `getTenantBillCycle()` can be implemented anywhere else.

```
function getTenantCurrency(tenant) {
    switch (tenant) {
        case 'company_denmark': return 'danish-crown';
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes this is a way smarter approach. this is working perfectly, thank you!